# NonNegative option in matlab odeset

Tags: matlab, ode

What exactly this option does? It seems it just set corresponding components of solution to zero without any error or retry with smaller step so I obtain corrupted solution. But if I limit a step then all looks OK (there are all components are positive). How can I restrict the solution components which should be strong positive?

Comment: Rewrite the system to replace these values by their logarithms. Then the exponential of the new variables will always be positive. Or use a solver for stiff systems.

Comment: I'm using solver for stiff systems ode15s so it returns good result (with all positive values) if I limit an integration step but in this case it runs too long and products too many values (as a result I need a workaround for case with out of memory).

Comment: @LutzL What do you mean "replace with their logarithms"?

Comment: Replace `x=exp(u)` resp.  `u=ln(x)` and accordingly `dotx=exp(u)*dotu`, if it were the only variable you would end up with changing `dotx=f(t,x)` to `dotu = exp(-u)*f(t,exp(u))`. But I'm not sure if it would be better than the implicit result.

Comment: It's much more complicated than "just set[ting] corresponding components of [a] solution to zero". See [this paper](http://www.radford.edu/~thompson/RP/nonnegative.pdf) (PDF) for a detailed discussion of this non-trivial problem.

Comment: How about using `ode113`? Or what happens if you adjust the tolerances (usually a better idea) rather than limiting the integration step? It's hard to really help much with out seeing runnable code for your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) NonNegative option allows check the solution at each integration step and replace negative values with zero (it could be OK for some problems)
2) In my case I've done the following steps:

1. Some code optimizations including analitical solution of linear algebraic equations system (which was solved at each integration step)
2. Using of AbsTol and RelTol. AbsTol should be less than variables in solution by several orders

Also in some cases it makes sense to try to solve equations without scaling